# Auto-increase string value by 1

Tags: android, mysql, database

I have to insert values in a database like this:

```
Location 1
Location 2
Location 3......
```

How can I increase the numberic value with same string?

Comment: Make static count and increase by 1 every time when you insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get number of entries added to Table in db and then increase it by one.Now you can add this number after "Location" word

Comment: Thanks alot my friend... You help me...